# This tag is hurting my [workflow]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, meta, burninate-request

The [workflow](/questions/tagged/workflow) tag has no tag wiki or excerpt, 11 questions, and is used for various kinds of workflows: those of users on Stack Exchange for many different scenarios, and even those of staff members. It looks like a typical [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) to me - any objections to it getting burninated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I went through and removed the workflow tag from the remaining three questions that had it. Hopefully, this tag will no longer hurt your workflow!

During the course of burnination, the community helped to close four questions previously tagged with [workflow](/questions/tagged/workflow) - [Q1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176280/622284), [Q2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114639/622284), [Q3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104839/622284), [Q4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/29276/622284). To those that helped vote to close, thanks for helping to clean up!

[image: dragon :)]

Answer (score 11):

I agree it should be burninated. A lot of the existing tags cover the specific workflows of each site functionality they refer to, like [review-audits](/questions/tagged/review-audits), [suggested-edits](/questions/tagged/suggested-edits), [declined-flags](/questions/tagged/declined-flags), etc...

My guess is there's already one tag for each workflow, so [workflow](/questions/tagged/workflow) is a meta tag.